# Is it possible to return passages.passage_text in search skill for Watson Assistant

Tags: watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I'm creating an assistant and want to be able to return relevant passages of text from documents uploaded to Watson Discovery via the Search Skill.

When configuring the search response you are only provided with the option to return the full text and various enriched_text.x extracted_metadata.x etc.

None of this is really that useful (for my use case anyway) and what I really need is to point the user to the relevant text within the documents i.e. return passages.passage_text

Am I missing something in the tooling or can you only do this by coding the API call from scratch?

Comment: This might be not possible at this point in time. Doing an API call from scratch e.g. using cloud functions might be the only way right now.